# Get dust.js to strip JavaScript comments

Tags: javascript, comments, dust.js

From the [github readme](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial):

> Take special care if you have a JavaScript code block and have comments of the form // message. When all the newlines are removed, this will comment out the following statement. Use the /* message */ form instead.

Ugh.  I understand syntactically why the removal of newlines disallows // style comments.

Is there a way to tell dust to just remove all comments?

If not, then external is probably how I'll roll (and would for production anyway - it's just annoying while doing early development work to remember to use c-style comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**: as of Dust 2.5.0 simply set

```
dust.config.whitespace = true;
```

---

Dust is just a string parser-- it doesn't grok the file that it's processing lexically.

You mentioned early development work, so a better option is probably to tell Dust to not strip whitespace, at least while you're developing.

After Dust has been loaded, simply override the behavior of the format optimizer:

```
dust.optimizers.format = function(ctx, node) { return node };
```

And Dust will stop stripping whitespace. In production, you probably want to use **uglify** or similar to remove comments anyways.

We are working on a better way to put this behind a flag in a future Dust version.